# force:CreateRecord not working

Tags: lightning-aura-components

force:CreateRecord not working with profiles other than admin in production (fired from quick action via custom component). Is there any permission needed for it?

Comment: Aside from the fact that the user would need Create permission on the object being created, there are no other requirements. Have you tried checking the Developer Console to see if you get any errors?

Comment: no there are no errors but the form doesn't open

Comment: and the profile have create permission